# CMOS layout: Simplification and Euler path

Tags: cmos, layout

[image]

what is the simplest form of Y = (logic)'  in order to find a Euler path common for pull-up and pull-down network and then implement it through CMOS layout?
I have issue finding the best form of the logic.
I have my work below but still think it is complicated and hard to find Euler path.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking for the ones in the Karnaugh map, you can look for the zeros in order to get an expression of Y in the form Y = (logic)'.

By considering the groups of zeros shown in the Karnaugh map below, you can straightforwardly derive this expression for Y:
$$Y = \overline{ BD + AD + \overline{A}B\overline{C} + \overline{A}\overline{C}D + \overline{B}C\overline{D} }$$
[image: Karnaugh map with explicit groups of zeros]

Then you can make some factorizations as follows, to reduce the number of transistors in the resulting gate:
$$Y = \overline{ D(B+A) + \overline{A}\overline{C}(B+D) + \overline{B}C\overline{D} }$$

Based on this expression of Y, you can draw the following circuit schematic (I labelled all nodes for clarity):

[image: Straightforward transistor-level circuit schematic]

The careful arrangement of the transistors in the pull-down network makes that there are exactly 2 nodes that are connected to an odd number of transistors: N and L. Hence an Euler path exists in the pull-down network.

In the pull-up network, there are also exactly 2 nodes that are connected to an odd number of transistors: V_DD and J. Hence an Euler path exists in the pull-up network.

Yet we want to find an Euler path that is common to both pull-up and pull-down networks. With the above circuit schematic it's not easy to find (maybe it's not possible). That is why I make the following modifications to the circuit schematic to make a common Euler path easily appear:

- in the pull-down network, swap some of the inputs
- in the pull-up network, swap two blocks of transistors that are in series (I mean that the blocks are in series, not the transistors)

Below is the resulting new circuit schematic:

[image: Modified transistor-level circuit schematic with explicit common Euler path]

This circuit still implements the logical function Y. This new arrangement allows to easily find an Euler path that is common to both pull-up and pull-down networks. For instance one can choose the following path:
$$B\hspace{5px}A\hspace{5px}D\hspace{5px}\overline{B}\hspace{5px}C\hspace{5px}\overline{D}\hspace{5px}\overline{C}\hspace{5px}\overline{A}\hspace{5px}B\hspace{5px}D$$

Using this common Euler path, we can layout the gate using an uninterrupted single line of diffusion for extra credit.

Below is a proposed Stick diagram for the layout.

[image: Proposed Stick diagram for the gate layout]

**Note:** By considering the groups of zeros shown in the Karnaugh map below instead of those that I considered above, we would derive a simpler expression of Y as follows:
$$Y = \overline{ BD + AD + \overline{C}D + \overline{A}B\overline{C} + \overline{B}C\overline{D} }$$
[image: Karnaugh map with more optimized groups of zeros]

which after factorization becomes:
$$Y = \overline{ D(B+A) + \overline{C}(D+\overline{A}B) + \overline{B}C\overline{D} }$$

This implementation has 10 transistors per network, like in the circuit schematics that I considered above. However I did not choose this one because it leads to higher parasitic capacitance as well as globally higher logical efforts for the possible inputs.